# How to take screenShot in gherkin-cucumber using testace as a framework?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cucumber, gherkin, testcafe

I´m trying to take a screenshot after a step failed:

```
const { After } = require('cucumber');

After(function (scenario) {
    if (scenario.result.status ==='failed') {
        var world = this;
        return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(screenShot, error) {
            if (!error) {
                world.attach(screenShot, "image/png");
            }
        });
    }
  });
```

It shows me an error with the browser:
ReferenceError: browser is not defined

Comment: have you named the webdriver as `driver` or `browser`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below. Make sure to match the webdriver var name matched as per your usage.

```
var {After, Status} = require('cucumber');

After(function (testCase) {
  var world = this;
  if (testCase.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
    // driver- update this with the correct webDriver variable
    return driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(screenShot) {
      // screenShot is a base-64 encoded PNG
      world.attach(screenShot, 'image/png');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thats correct, but my concern is where the driver variable is geted. Do i need to install something, like a webdriver?

Comment: Do you see the browser opened when you run the test? If yes, then you have to use the WebDriver instance name from that step.